# Sever returning 400 when body passed with GET

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes

I have an Express GET route to fetch all users. Whenever a `req.body` is present, the server is always responding with `400`.

Obviously, I have `body-parser` and this behaviour is only experienced in the production k8s environment (working fine in localhost)

Is there any limitation to send `req.body` to `GET` routes? [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) doesn't say so

Comment: Potentially proxy/middleware may just not propagate it, as it's not standard:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/978094/1075282

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type `--header "Content-Type: application/json"`  in the `GET` request and it should work.

```
 curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request GET  --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' https://example.com/posttest
```

and here is the nodejs snippet

```
app.get('/posttest', function(req, res){
  console.log("posttest call received")
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

[image]

Comment: --header "Content-Type: application/json"  its already there.  Thats why this is weird :-)

Comment: https://github.com/Adiii717/nodejs-backend-hello-world

Comment: i was able to get response body, here is the working example that you can try